# How to show many datasets inside one dataset

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

Basically, I have some stored procedures on SQL Server with an "ID" as parameter (let's call it ItemId), and DataTables called dt_item1, dt_item2 and so, with the results of those procedures.

Now I have a new parameter (let's call it PlaceId) and I managed to put all the dt_item tables inside a Dataset ds_place, matching all the items (ItemId) in that place, using *while*.

The problem begins with a SP with "UserId" as a parameter, that retrieve a list of places that belongs to that user.

What I need is to put all the results of many ds_place inside one dataset called ds_user.

Comment: What have tried so far?  Would help if we could see your code

Comment: + 1 on seeing some code and sample results of the stored procs. First question that springs to mind is, why do this in your code, when you could look at getting the data you need from another stored proc?